# Writing a hex pattern via sscan f

Tags: c++, c, embedded, hex

My two variables are both 32 bit unsigned integers. Not sure why this does not seem to work:

```
// Arguments: output_file how_many_mb 

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    uint32_t pattern, counter;
    int i, count;
    counter = 1;
    sscanf(&counter, "%x", &pattern); 
    FILE * outFile = fopen(argv[1],"wb");
    int times = atoi(argv[2]);
    count = 0;

    times = times*1048576; // Write out 4bytes at a time

    for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        fwrite(&pattern, 1, 1, outFile);
        counter<<=1;
        sscanf(&counter, "%x", &pattern);  
        count++;

        if (counter == 0) { 
            sscanf("00000000", "%x", &pattern);  
                if (count < 100)
                printf ("Reached the condition %0x \n", pattern);   
            counter = 1;    
        }
        if (count < 100)
            printf ("%x\n", pattern);
        }
        fclose (outFile);
    }
```

I'm essentially trying to "write" a hex pattern to a file. I bit shift counter and then write it to pattern as hex. That is the statement that is causing me problems. The created file essentially has garbage inside it.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here to answer the question. What goes wrong? What are your expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: The first argument to `sscanf()` must be a pointer to (const) char, ie: it must be a string.

Comment: is there an easy way to do this? besides having to run through all the cases and checking? Thanks.

Comment: There's no way this compiled without any warnings.  Read what your compiler is telling you and, while you're at it, read the documentation for `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 4):

You are using sscanf incorrectly (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/)

```
int32_t counter;
const char * pattern = "badf00d";
sscanf(pattern, "%x", &counter);
```